# python convert string representation of nested list of integers to nested list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read the string representation of a nested list and convert it to a nested list in python. I have tried the following:

```
l=input("enter nested list")
result=eval(l)
```

with input `[[1],[2]]`
and result is the string I just entered so that if I `print(l[0])` the result is `'['`. 
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the input list you have tried to your question as well?

Comment: can you post an example of input-desired output?

Comment: You store the the result in `result` variable. Why are you checking `print(l[0])`?

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem. `eval` does work but is not the right thing to do and as such it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` is unsafe as it does not run any *background* checks on the input. Use `literal_eval` from built-in module `ast` instead. You can write:

```
from ast import literal_eval as leval

l = '[[1],[2]]'
result = leval(l)
print(result)     # -> [[1], [2]]
print(result[0])  # -> [1]
```

---

The problem with your code, as @bro-grammer points out is that you assume that `eval` works *in-place* and when you do `eval(l)` `l` is modified. **That is not how it works though**. `eval` returns its result and assigns it to `result` in your code. Try doing `print(result[0])` instead and you will see.

Comment: Check my answer . You cannot use `eval` but you can use `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `eval` but `exec`. No need to import any module.

```
l = input("Enter nested list: ")
exec('result = '+l)
print(result)
print(result[0])
```

Testing:

```
Enter nested list: [[1],[2]]
[[1], [2]]
[1]
```